# How to use scaling shaders in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader, scaling

I am trying to make a use of scaling shaders in WebGL (super-xbr in particular), but I fail to properly pass the data to the shader so it does the correct interpolation. I've converted GLSL shader to the corresponding vertex and fragment shaders and it was all working great upon I tried to actually do scaling with them.

This is how I define gl_Position to get image twice as big (and this is probably where I am making a mistake):

```
        // Added 2x multiplication to the original code
        vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution * 2.0;
        vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
        vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
        gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
```

This gets the job done, but shader does not interpolate the image. Here is the result (top is source with nearest neighbor interpolation, bottom is the result of the program):

[image: Test result]

This is the approximated desired result:

[image]

The program itself is basically a copy of [WebGL2 fundamentals tutorial](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html), which does basic rectangle painting. The only thing I changed there is to make canvas twice as big.

Full code below (results better viewed on high dpi monitor)

```js
!(function(window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    function main() {
        var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]; // MUST BE SAME DOMAIN!!!
        image.onload = function() {
            render(image);
        }
    }

    function render(image) {
        // Get A WebGL context
        /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.naturalWidth * 2;
        canvas.height = image.naturalHeight * 2;
        canvas.style.width = image.naturalWidth + 'px';
        canvas.style.height = image.naturalHeight + 'px';        
        var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
        if (!gl) {
            return;
        }

        // setup GLSL program
        var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);

        // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
        var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
        var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

        // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
        var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

        // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
        // Set a rectangle the same size as the image.
        setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

        // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
        var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
            0.0, 0.0,
            1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 1.0,
            1.0, 0.0,
            1.0, 1.0,
        ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        // Create a texture.
        var texture = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

        // Upload the image into the texture.
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

        // lookup uniforms
        var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");

        //webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

        // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        // Clear the canvas
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
        gl.useProgram(program);

        // Turn on the position attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

        // Bind the position buffer.
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

        // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
        var size = 2; // 2 components per iteration
        var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
        var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
        var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
        var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

        // Turn on the texcord attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

        // Bind the position buffer.
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

        // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
        var size = 2; // 2 components per iteration
        var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
        var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
        var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
        var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

        // set the resolution
        gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        // Draw the rectangle.
        var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
        var offset = 0;
        var count = 6;
        gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
    }

    function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
        var x1 = x;
        var x2 = x + width;
        var y1 = y;
        var y2 = y + height;
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
            x1, y1,
            x2, y1,
            x1, y2,
            x1, y2,
            x2, y1,
            x2, y2,
        ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);

})(window, document, undefined);
```

```css
       html, body
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body 
        {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .container,
        .canvas
        {
            margin: auto;
        }

        img
        {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            image-rendering: pixelated;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">#version 300 es

        #ifdef GL_ES
        #define COMPAT_PRECISION mediump
        #else
        #define COMPAT_PRECISION
        #endif

        #if __VERSION__ >= 130
        #define COMPAT_VARYING out
        #define COMPAT_ATTRIBUTE in
        #define COMPAT_TEXTURE texture
        #else
        #define COMPAT_VARYING varying
        #define COMPAT_ATTRIBUTE attribute
        #define COMPAT_TEXTURE texture2D
        #endif

        COMPAT_ATTRIBUTE vec2 a_position;
        COMPAT_ATTRIBUTE vec2 a_texCoord;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 TEX0;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t1;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t2;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t3;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t4;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t5;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t6;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t7;

        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION int FrameDirection;
        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION int FrameCount;
        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION vec2 OutputSize;
        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION vec2 TextureSize;
        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION vec2 InputSize;
        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION vec2 u_resolution;

        // compatibility #defines
        #define vTexCoord TEX0.xy
        #define SourceSize vec4(TextureSize, 1.0 / TextureSize) //either TextureSize or InputSize
        #define OutSize vec4(OutputSize, 1.0 / OutputSize)

        void main()
        {
            //gl_Position = MVPMatrix * VertexCoord;

            // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
            vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution * 2.0;

            // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
            vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

            // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
            vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

            gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);


            TEX0.xy = a_texCoord.xy * 1.0004;
            vec2 ps = vec2(1.0/ SourceSize.x, 1.0/ SourceSize.y);
            float dx = ps.x;
            float dy = ps.y;

            //    A1 B1 C1
            // A0  A  B  C C4
            // D0  D  E  F F4
            // G0  G  H  I I4
            //    G5 H5 I5

            t1 = vTexCoord.xxxy + vec4( -dx, 0, dx,-2.0*dy); // A1 B1 C1
            t2 = vTexCoord.xxxy + vec4( -dx, 0, dx,    -dy); //  A  B  C
            t3 = vTexCoord.xxxy + vec4( -dx, 0, dx,      0); //  D  E  F
            t4 = vTexCoord.xxxy + vec4( -dx, 0, dx,     dy); //  G  H  I
            t5 = vTexCoord.xxxy + vec4( -dx, 0, dx, 2.0*dy); // G5 H5 I5
            t6 = vTexCoord.xyyy + vec4(-2.0*dx,-dy, 0,  dy); // A0 D0 G0
            t7 = vTexCoord.xyyy + vec4( 2.0*dx,-dy, 0,  dy); // C4 F4 I4

        }
    </script>
    <script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">#version 300 es

        #ifdef GL_ES
        #ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
        precision highp float;
        #else
        precision mediump float;
        #endif
        #define COMPAT_PRECISION mediump
        #else
        #define COMPAT_PRECISION
        #endif

        #define mul(a,b) (b*a)

        // Constants used with gamma correction.
        #define InputGamma 2.4
        #define OutputGamma 2.2

        #define GAMMA_IN(color) pow(color, vec3(InputGamma, InputGamma, InputGamma))
        #define GAMMA_OUT(color) pow(color, vec3(1.0 / OutputGamma, 1.0 / OutputGamma, 1.0 / OutputGamma))


        #if __VERSION__ >= 130
        #define COMPAT_VARYING in
        #define COMPAT_TEXTURE texture
        out COMPAT_PRECISION vec4 FragColor;
        #else
        #define COMPAT_VARYING varying
        #define FragColor gl_FragColor
        #define COMPAT_TEXTURE texture2D
        #endif

        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION int FrameDirection;
        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION int FrameCount;
        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION vec2 OutputSize;
        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION vec2 TextureSize;
        uniform COMPAT_PRECISION vec2 InputSize;
        uniform sampler2D Texture;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 TEX0;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t1;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t2;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t3;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t4;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t5;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t6;
        COMPAT_VARYING vec4 t7;

        // compatibility #defines
        #define Source Texture
        #define vTexCoord TEX0.xy
        #define texture(c, d) COMPAT_TEXTURE(c, d)
        #define SourceSize vec4(TextureSize, 1.0 / TextureSize) //either TextureSize or InputSize
        #define OutSize vec4(OutputSize, 1.0 / OutputSize)

        const float coef           = 2.0;
        const vec4 eq_threshold  = vec4(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0);
        const float y_weight        = 1.0;
        const float u_weight        = 7.0;
        const float v_weight        = 6.0;
        const mat3x3 yuv          = mat3x3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114, -0.169, -0.331, 0.499, 0.499, -0.418, -0.0813);
        const mat3x3 yuv_weighted = mat3x3(y_weight*yuv[0], u_weight*yuv[1], v_weight*yuv[2]);
        const vec4 delta         = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        const float sharpness      = 0.65;

        float lum(vec3 A, vec3 B)
        {
            return abs(dot(A-B, yuv_weighted[0]));
        }

        vec4 df(vec4 A, vec4 B)
        {
            return vec4(abs(A-B));
        }

        bvec4 eq(vec4 A, vec4 B)
        {
            return lessThan(df(A, B) , vec4(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0));
        }

        bvec4 eq2(vec4 A, vec4 B)
        {
            return lessThan(df(A, B) , vec4(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0));
        }

        bvec4 eq3(vec4 A, vec4 B)
        {
            return lessThan(df(A, B) , vec4(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
        }


        vec4 weighted_distance(vec4 a, vec4 b, vec4 c, vec4 d, vec4 e, vec4 f, vec4 g, vec4 h)
        {
            return (df(a,b) + df(a,c) + df(d,e) + df(d,f) + 4.0*df(g,h));
        }

        bvec4 and(bvec4 A, bvec4 B)
        {
            return bvec4(A.x && B.x, A.y && B.y, A.z && B.z, A.w && B.w);
        }

        bvec4 or(bvec4 A, bvec4 B)
        {
            return bvec4(A.x || B.x, A.y || B.y, A.z || B.z, A.w || B.w);
        }

        void main()
        {
            bvec4 edr, edr_left, edr_up, px; // px = pixel, edr = edge detection rule
            bvec4 interp_restriction_lv1, interp_restriction_lv2_left, interp_restriction_lv2_up;
            bvec4 nc, nc30, nc60, nc45; // new_color
            vec4 fx, fx_left, fx_up, final_fx; // inequations of straight lines.

            vec2 fp = fract(vTexCoord*SourceSize.xy);

            vec3 A1 = texture(Source, t1.xw).rgb;
            vec3 B1 = texture(Source, t1.yw).rgb;
            vec3 C1 = texture(Source, t1.zw).rgb;

            vec3 A  = texture(Source, t2.xw).rgb;
            vec3 B  = texture(Source, t2.yw).rgb;
            vec3 C  = texture(Source, t2.zw).rgb;

            vec3 D  = texture(Source, t3.xw).rgb;
            vec3 E  = texture(Source, t3.yw).rgb;
            vec3 F  = texture(Source, t3.zw).rgb;

            vec3 G  = texture(Source, t4.xw).rgb;
            vec3 H  = texture(Source, t4.yw).rgb;
            vec3 I  = texture(Source, t4.zw).rgb;

            vec3 G5 = texture(Source, t5.xw).rgb;
            vec3 H5 = texture(Source, t5.yw).rgb;
            vec3 I5 = texture(Source, t5.zw).rgb;

            vec3 A0 = texture(Source, t6.xy).rgb;
            vec3 D0 = texture(Source, t6.xz).rgb;
            vec3 G0 = texture(Source, t6.xw).rgb;

            vec3 C4 = texture(Source, t7.xy).rgb;
            vec3 F4 = texture(Source, t7.xz).rgb;
            vec3 I4 = texture(Source, t7.xw).rgb;

            vec4 b = mul( mat4x3(B, D, H, F), yuv_weighted[0] );
            vec4 c = mul( mat4x3(C, A, G, I), yuv_weighted[0] );
            vec4 e = mul( mat4x3(E, E, E, E), yuv_weighted[0] );
            vec4 a = c.yzwx;
            vec4 d = b.yzwx;
            vec4 f = b.wxyz;
            vec4 g = c.zwxy;
            vec4 h = b.zwxy;
            vec4 i = c.wxyz;

            vec4 i4 = mul( mat4x3(I4, C1, A0, G5), yuv_weighted[0] );
            vec4 i5 = mul( mat4x3(I5, C4, A1, G0), yuv_weighted[0] );
            vec4 h5 = mul( mat4x3(H5, F4, B1, D0), yuv_weighted[0] );
            vec4 f4 = h5.yzwx;


            vec4 Ao = vec4( 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0 );
            vec4 Bo = vec4( 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,-1.0 );
            vec4 Co = vec4( 1.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
            vec4 Ax = vec4( 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0 );
            vec4 Bx = vec4( 0.5,  2.0, -0.5,-2.0 );
            vec4 Cx = vec4( 1.0,  1.0, -0.5, 0.0 );
            vec4 Ay = vec4( 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0 );
            vec4 By = vec4( 2.0,  0.5, -2.0,-0.5 );
            vec4 Cy = vec4( 2.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.5 );

            // These inequations define the line below which interpolation occurs.
            fx      = (Ao*fp.y+Bo*fp.x);
            fx_left = (Ax*fp.y+Bx*fp.x);
            fx_up   = (Ay*fp.y+By*fp.x);

            //this is the only way I can keep these comparisons straight '-_-
            bvec4 block1 = and(not(eq(h,h5)) , not(eq(h,i5)));
            bvec4 block2 = and(not(eq(f,f4)) , not(eq(f,i4)));
            bvec4 block3 = and(not(eq(h, d)) , not(eq(h, g)));
            bvec4 block4 = and(not(eq(f, b)) , not(eq(f, c)));
            bvec4 block5 = and(eq(e, i) , or(block2 , block1));

            bvec4 block_comp = or(block4 , or(block3 , or(block5 , or(eq(e,g) , eq(e,c)))));

            interp_restriction_lv1      = and(notEqual(e,f) , and(notEqual(e,h) , block_comp));
            interp_restriction_lv2_left = and(notEqual(e,g) , notEqual(d,g));
            interp_restriction_lv2_up   = and(notEqual(e,c) , notEqual(b,c));

            vec4 fx45 = smoothstep(Co - delta, Co + delta, fx);
            vec4 fx30 = smoothstep(Cx - delta, Cx + delta, fx_left);
            vec4 fx60 = smoothstep(Cy - delta, Cy + delta, fx_up);


            edr      = and(lessThan((weighted_distance( e, c, g, i, h5, f4, h, f) + 3.5) , weighted_distance( h, d, i5, f, i4, b, e, i)) , interp_restriction_lv1);
            edr_left = and(lessThanEqual((coef*df(f,g)) , df(h,c)) , interp_restriction_lv2_left);
            edr_up   = and(greaterThanEqual(df(f,g) , (coef*df(h,c))) , interp_restriction_lv2_up);

            nc45 = and( edr ,                bvec4(fx45));
            nc30 = and( edr , and(edr_left , bvec4(fx30)));
            nc60 = and( edr , and(edr_up   , bvec4(fx60)));

            px = lessThanEqual(df(e,f) , df(e,h));

            vec3 res = E;


            vec3 n1, n2, n3, n4, s, aa, bb, cc, dd;


            n1 = B1; n2 = B; s = E; n3 = H; n4 = H5;
            aa = n2-n1; bb = s-n2; cc = n3-s; dd = n4-n3;

            vec3 t = (7. * (bb + cc) - 3. * (aa + dd)) / 16.;

            vec3 m;
            m.x = (s.x < 0.5) ? 2.*s.x : 2.*(1.0-s.x);
            m.y = (s.y < 0.5) ? 2.*s.y : 2.*(1.0-s.y);
            m.z = (s.z < 0.5) ? 2.*s.z : 2.*(1.0-s.z);

                m = min(m, sharpness*abs(bb));
                m = min(m, sharpness*abs(cc));

            t = clamp(t, -m, m);


            vec3 s1 = (2.*fp.y-1.)*t + s;

            n1 = D0; n2 = D; s = s1; n3 = F; n4 = F4;
            aa = n2-n1; bb = s-n2; cc = n3-s; dd = n4-n3;

            t = (7. * (bb + cc) - 3. * (aa + dd)) / 16.;

            m.x = (s.x < 0.5) ? 2.*s.x : 2.*(1.0-s.x);
            m.y = (s.y < 0.5) ? 2.*s.y : 2.*(1.0-s.y);
            m.z = (s.z < 0.5) ? 2.*s.z : 2.*(1.0-s.z);

                m = min(m, sharpness*abs(bb));
                m = min(m, sharpness*abs(cc));

            t = clamp(t, -m, m);

            vec3 s0 = (2.*fp.x-1.)*t + s;


            nc = or(nc30 , or(nc60 , nc45));

            float blend = 0.0;
            vec3 pix;

            vec4 r1 = mix(e, f, edr);

            bool yeseq3=false;
            bvec4 yes;

            if ( all(eq3(r1,e)) )
            {
                yeseq3 = true;
                pix = res = s0;
            }
            else
            {
                pix = res = E;
            }

            yes = and(bvec4(yeseq3) , eq2(e, mix(f, h, px)));

            vec4 final45 = vec4(nc45) * fx45;
            vec4 final30 = vec4(nc30) * fx30;
            vec4 final60 = vec4(nc60) * fx60;

            vec4 maximo = max(max(final30, final60), final45);

                 if (nc.x) {pix = px.x ? F : H; blend = maximo.x; if (yes.x)  pix = res = s0; else res=E;}
            else if (nc.y) {pix = px.y ? B : F; blend = maximo.y; if (yes.y)  pix = res = s0; else res=E;}
            else if (nc.z) {pix = px.z ? D : B; blend = maximo.z; if (yes.z)  pix = res = s0; else res=E;}
            else if (nc.w) {pix = px.w ? H : D; blend = maximo.w; if (yes.w)  pix = res = s0; else res=E;}

            res = GAMMA_IN(res);
            pix = GAMMA_IN(pix);

            res = mix(res, pix, blend);

           FragColor = vec4(clamp( GAMMA_OUT(res), 0.0, 1.0 ), 1.0);
        }
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSgBBwcHCggKEwoKEygaFhooKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKP/CABEIAIAAgAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAdAAAABwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBQYHBAgJ/9oACAEBAAAAAPKgAMAGEgBaAAD6r7ZhXc5ZAMgHejW/QnVGwjZ+d6W2tfGHfTnplFZz6GiYcY3X3k8w1f3K+iNrmSVavw3ZmPKRH7m1IuSLgqfkUIz01+kBXV9Ge3mj4Gr1SuVNvkmMfSdk9j3bOlcVWi3KvHR8jkCTlPTrGabFCtOuxdNZmMIID0tRlaC644aMxS7j5OuX2Uirjc+g2uPJnomtD3M4Wd5DO9dqRFQeYegNZSDUpOfxfDCQcBC7ftDQLqNHOql4NU4no1GR50H0bz39awCCwSQhSzNJEHEKCDBLT//EABsBAAEFAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAgMEBQYH/9oACAECEAAAAEjPWKShi6rb4B0g4CCh7Zv8BZZ5NYm2vXsOiOPbSb6BrZcGfSx2dloVYG54u3mGEIEo/wD/xAAbAQABBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAECBAUGB//aAAgBAxAAAABJqlgiSWbyuZ6Fei9sh+DF1sX3LAA+f6+i/pWdjy46psH6DazQc4CyZXo16k0R2eLsv//EACoQAAICAQQBBAICAgMAAAAAAAECAwQFAAYREgcQEyExFSIIIBQyQVFh/9oACAEBAAEIAP7H0H/v3/XgdOf7caoUbN6wsFTD+Hd3ZFFeWDwJdCA25PA9hlK1dxeF96YSMzNYhkgmeOf1J+AP6RRmQnhaXY8Dxr4Zt5oJf3Bt/bmJ27UFfDzNwTq5OBzq3OWJGqGet4th7O5MTtrf1Jjkd7ePLW27DSCeusSFkhieZ+qNTlB409RooxK3pGf0kA/jz4WjnqVt0btgpV4kCxWcfWmQiTMbcYqzUcp71ad4bFibgHVqwODzNkZKsyywXs5Hk6jxzbqxf492/wAaKaSIkxi7Mf8AeawZF6n0/jzsJd6bzWS+gUBVWJwGGrU45I1PLwNZ+rWyVZorW4as+LsmKa7a451kLQbkAzOk4dbdaLI49gb9Z6VySB+eDonn0H3r+OG2l274yoSP26g693g8ieb7LW7PAOrtv4OtwSw3a7wT5oyVbLwu5LEkyqNYiUR2PYfyDj+hhtr64mo1/J1KceGevHWNKpJJ8HUknUHi1P8AGr9wL21lciFVtXLvYkjNUzegLqV++Z4ihHL8qwK5yKDJbTvvIfv18cor7928H29nRW8jZ/FzyzDW+/IlfDPJTx22rs42/XsZLJ5QcNxkLhmJ6lHY8ssDjgjP49694mOeKz7HLmMvz1rF4tu3lkPrtq7+P3BjLjeTe1HdDZCruTyfZuYSCtQrhrd6Cutu8EX21sTtKTpV+RyiAaCjW5a/u4xpFkmlYcMAC3xFUjs7cy4mYcMRofJA9B9jVrPVty+ONr22vnrz12oS25Kh0zNK37Kn1oKBpV9J4xNBJE00qx8hqsySydV37cGP2Oauifn09mXnjS0rLf6+LshIslrCWMsrJI6mN3ilWSPCbs4CRZWlNBci92oEP3orxqRwo5aa1weFvz8WJQNrRve3BXhi36cnm84z1/weWP1+Cyx+mqxnkgQqdLUQHkeRtmJZie7j6+LNjJw1HOxLoP609m268glWpHLWh6WbFpVBC27wBJ1fyyQxO7WLvYsT4O2RLiqJzeZZj9AMf+OS3PPsxdgdKgX40R8NplLHht6bEW47XcPHeAqhrdrNQICFu7giBJN3csXB4u7kU89Xt3s5ZTH4rxX4dXEzQ5fdrMT8sW/6DHXfjQi7fsDCOAHmX2QpUNZ566LEOsa77ihyErV7e6cFmFkkOGt4fdUKM9mSvlGH74mOOGx3ym3fKUm2qzQYB/Ou5gONP543NyOT523Ox5C+ct0FviLzVutvgRbbxsQUR1cfFTIIACAkniONnbqyxlpIlPUdo2KoNQyBo1YRL2iHEURaPghSQwbqSSGAPJV+qsxU9QGUaLMPghBGmhGV5d05dy7FezcLMhZkTUylY2KBQAA0ABhU6jUqXCkmN+NSM6kPp+T8jqrKHUftyGDAABuCnwP/xAA/EAEAAQMBBQUFBQUGBwAAAAABAgADESEEEjFBUQVhcYGRECIyodEGEyCxwRRCguHwIyQwM3KEUmKSk6LC8f/aAAgBAQAJPwD/ABpGemufx7Pev3ZcIW4Ml8itit7Fbee1XSLj/SZflXbey23mW7Mp49Ur7Tdnl3lDabFy0P8AEbx612ZHb9miZ+92C4XjHXBiXyq3O3cg4lCcWKPRHU/wGIGqrgraNn/6/wCVTdk7OliULUdLl08/hO/jWw2dlgGsoHvS75S4r4tOlNNTzYzram5i+HR7ytjh+1xMN2OI37feSOJ45K2q1d7OXEL8hE7pAOHv4VftXYjj3M/qFGoZfCipQcJ7uvt5h+ZVlY3AubFsUjGTiXJ+PEOmrxKsW4xDgRKsW3PMMPqVdzLH+XcdHwfrUJ27pxjIw+Ph3001Nt3IuSUeX9dKIsk3blpMidTu/KhdknPMTHwvSpsV44alvePGuHtt7/ZHZ5G/tInu3HPuW3xRXuHrQEImADBitdeFBppTio5xncmfFF7n9KwxllhMNJHd39TlTT6U6no91AxmOB5PMrVi6KcTk0HpWPbDd2vtLO23ng4lpA8oh5rTX50001rF1E4xlyTvp96PCRwkck9r7t3h3Jw9eFRxl3JIen4Pjv3YWjxlIP1rS3sO7s2703YmD0T2cimmnXxp40ZvQGUccznH+udFHIzSkhyPRqCz/Zy7bQ4THL5YJH4Phe0LGf8AuFTCO1XS5ay/vkTJ5mPSnXuphtPaEfdk5zC09+OL3Hm8quzubZtQ7RdlJ114AcADd0KzUVoaH0qDuXjeAOfM/rrUJoqPu66YelGUqKRITNeiP8/wOI7PtNu6vcTH9Kn93cvRt7RC4cRNMnmFQls22Thjabw4w8Et9M8c8s4OtKyvXIw49XD+tLuxN0OgaFLj8GSVlJicccH5flV2bHoyaKuW7MSw4uXHBGSIK+KVycfgWe3WrLs9/ubeIue9SKeLTpnNa/drc9Iv60vtPZwnFi+ZipGTRKfe6c2kL3aV+MSPP7u37y+GWJ7bc97puua2e8+Ftf0qEy3tP9pZUTF0MY8zTxChE0qUoTi5JRcI9zUGRwL1s1/iOfielXrd6HWLnHicvP2oVoZ40/vv5tGfik9wH/yuztu/YdniWNn/ALvMzEVZcOMlZeZ0rsvbn/bz+ldl7e/7ef0q3b3k1WJmsZ6mlQt5dc4Fq0F7LKUYnx9THXmPPhUyy3Jbu9IUHkeulbZs2O8kfpXaZZnH96zFz65K2ue0yOE5wIvy41jxqWaQIjJ8jNOF1datShtm1RGxZmYbVviSkcl445GKZodFxTc9WmfhvNQhnvNK3T5UQTry/nRHdTWKZ3vHoViG1Rd5jnG88cnfR9ztB7ty3LRjLnp86mebVwfOpnrUvnWz3tq2q+7pbswZSl4B+fCi3tHaEEnZ2ISVuy8SUnhKRyD3R6vBzzdHPnSlPlisJ4UrF/4QV+dCGQIoZfHWoSuTk4jGEVDxcaHfVgJJnelvYDvxHTz41Bm4zIwmnpzr7JdsdpXLYhf7P3I3I6HCTIU7kTursj7XRjF/y9s2ImnUZQ5/w12T2nbiJFZbNMwpnp0a2basdW1L6V2Vt+22xP7K3cbQ+Lur6Yr7A7JsdqQEkbspz/1TTL5tfZfZo44ZjeyV2BsME57l3612P2YZ5Nu7r/5V2R2Z3x+6uv8A7V2DsNx/5bN7PyaNoJ403NoTB3dCr20T3nAXL295GaFkvEVy0T4ZcZpc/E68KcSdXWt855F61K7r0y86nN46MqXJom84qasdH3mlU55amZNTv+dSMhkxzPrSnMkaVKWOG9l+tK5emq8qnh46AET+udSmRxiOTDjm6nOtIjl3nA9xpQuXKGXQ1+lEmWMAMjWsnL41rXJphaNBXi89aAJZQzxedGImjjXTr5UmTkJrSZOD0+dMSXhx7zWk6b2DWklHmvE+tf/EAC8RAAEDAwIFAgQHAQAAAAAAAAEAAgMEESEFMQYQEhNRIkFhcZHhFSAyM0KBobH/2gAIAQIBAT8A5AEmwTaWZwuGlSOELumX0384/wC/lmqI4G9UhsFFxDBFkRm3laXqdLqH7L8+4O6npIamMxzNBB8rUdIn0d/dpyXQncHJao3h4DhssctW1Hv1Lmg+luB/W6/EHdgxj3KhqZYJBJESCM3BXDXEQ1OHomxKB9fipgJGljhcHcKSE0NUYD+k5HKUlrC4ewVSwxu+efqm072xB7xYHbyVBBc3Ko53UcrZYzkG/wBlS1baqFszTuL/AGXEMQLGTDdpH0PJw6gW+VHRMJDZRctWoMBc1vgXVwMBErhKpLoHwu/icfIrVbPj6D7kf5y73wVUPV3AMe6nfA4ASGymawH0OumRkrhlhh7jjsVV1YkfjYLvfBEhFzdlU0DZ7dJso9HAySFHprGblMBYzoZgLtOKETlnkQrAIWWFhBf/xAArEQABAwIEBAUFAAAAAAAAAAABAAIDBBEFITFBEBITUQYgImGBIzIzceH/2gAIAQMBAT8A4EgC5T6+nYbF4UM0c4vG4H9eUgkekXKqMOnqPuf8bLEaWek/IMjvsqaaWJ4fGSCNwsNxEVjOSUWeN9iiCMlnwjZYe6bFc3T6aOVhjkAIOoKxLAxRyc0ebDp7KD6RBbqFDIKiESDUa8Gi5sp6R0Lg07gEfIRo3xxiVwsDorKeATsMbhkVUQuglMbtQVg8nrMRORHAGxuqEQ1dNFJKLloy/qxiUySBo0AQaUAvElPyzNkbuFhTS1/N2HDojusJr+gOg85HQ9lO2J1ucqSJjT6TdGwWOAS8jRsqWl6bc9SuiO6zWaZXPDQ2TMDQ7o142BT60nQIkOdzOzK6gXVbxz83/9k=" alt="testimage" />
    </div>
    <div class="canvas">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use **`gl.LINEAR`**, - `gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);` `gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed it, now going to find better shaders.

Comment: @Rabbid76 , if you don't mind, can you help me with [this one](https://i.imgur.com/xG4zBAo.jpg)? What could be the cause of this?

Comment: I can only guess, but maybe its a depth buffer issue and you have to clear the depth buffer `gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | ` **`gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`** `);` or you have to disable the depth test `gl.disable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );`

Comment: @Rabbid76 , thanks for the help, unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. It probably has something to do with the `gl_Position` since I use a custom function to set it, instead of a shader's default one, which always looks like this: `gl_Position = MVPMatrix * VertexCoord;`. Don't really know if that affects the processing.